# Precise Definition of the Eigenvalues of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. The definition of eigenvalues that I was told of was, $A\vec x = \lambda \vec x$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Furthermore, we commonly refer to a set $S$ as the eigenvalues of $A$. To me, this seems that $S$ is always the same for a fixed matrix $A$. However, if $\vec x$ is a vector such that $A\vec x = \lambda \vec x$. Then, for all $c \in \mathbb R$, isn't $c\vec x$ also a vector that satisfies this? Since, 
$$A(c\vec x) = c(A\vec x) = (c\lambda) \vec x$$
Thus, it seems to me that $c\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue, and therefore also in $S$. Thus, it looks like every element of $\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue, so long as the matrix has at least one such non-zero eigenvector. I further understand that solving for $|A - I\lambda| = 0$ yields exactly $n$ (possibly non-distinct) eigenvalues.

My question is, what is the canonical set of eigenvalues? And can two different sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ both be the "set of eigenvalues of matrix $A$". If so, how can the definition of something like [Spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) be well defined?

Spectral radius is defined as
$$\rho(A) = \max \{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\}$$

By my previous claim that every element of $\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue to a corresponding eigenvector, it feels like I can always find a larger eigenvalue than $\rho(A)$.

Comment: It is $A(c\vec x) = c(A\vec x) = (c\lambda) \vec x=\lambda(c\vec x)$ and so the eigenvalues don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use $A(c\mathbf{x}) = (c\lambda)\mathbf{x}$ to claim that $c \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix A. This is incorrect: You have $A(c\mathbf{x}) = c\lambda \mathbf{x} = \lambda( c \mathbf{x} )$, so all this equation does is demonstrate that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the eigenvector $c\mathbf{x}$ as well as the vector $\mathbf{x}$. This does not imply that $c\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first equation
$$A(cx) = (c\lambda)x$$
is not in the form of an eigenvector equation. Let,
$$\begin{align*}
v_1 &:= cx \\
\lambda^* &:= c\lambda \\
v_2 &:= x
\end{align*}$$
Then your equation reads,
$$Av_1 = \lambda^*v_2$$
where $v_1 \neq v_2$ which is clearly just some vector equation, not an eigenvector equation (even if it is true that $v_1$ is a scaling of $v_2$.

Instead, we reorganize the equation (through a simple change in multiplication association) as,
$$A(cx) = \lambda(cx)$$
so that if we define
$$v := cx$$
it reads
$$Av = \lambda v$$
which is indeed the form of an eigenvector equation. Note that the same $\lambda$ is still sitting there, unchanged.

The take away is that *eigenvectors* are not unique, or rather, they are unique *up to a change in scale*. In that light one might call them "eigendirections." The associated eigenvalues, however, are unique given $A$.